# How does Hydras sweeper, specifically Ax-sweeper free/allocate memory?

Tags: fb-hydra

So I'm using Hydra 1.1 and `hydra-ax-sweeper==1.1.5` to manage my configuration, and run some hyper-parameter optimization on [minerl environment](https://github.com/minerllabs/minerl). For this purpose, I load a lot of data in to memory (peak around 50Gb while loading with multiprocessing, drops to 30Gb after fully loaded) with multiprocessing (by pytorch).

On a normal run this is not a problem (My machine have 90+Gb RAM), one training finish without any issue.

However, when I run the same code with `-m` option (and `hydra/sweeper: ax` in config), the code stops after about 2-3 sweeper runs, getting stuck at the data loading phase, because all memories of the system (+swap memory) is occupied.

First I thought this was some issue with `minerl` environment code, which starts java-code in sub-process. So I tried to run my code without the environment (only the 30Gb data), and I still have the same issue. So I suspect I have some memory-leak inbetween the Hydra sweeper.

So my question is, How does Hydra sweeper(or ax-sweeper) work in-between sweeps? I always had the impression that it runs the `main(cfg: DictConfig)` decorated with `@hydra.main(...)`, takes a scalar return(score) and run the Bayesian optimizer with this score, with `main()` called similar to a function (everything inside being properly deallocated/garbage collected **between** each sweep-run).

Is this not the case? Should I then load the data somewhere outside the `main()` and keep it between sweeps?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hydra-ax-sweeper` may run trials in parallel, depending on the result of calling the `get_max_parallelism` function defined in `ax.service.ax_client`.
I suspect that your machine is running out of memory because of this parallelism.

Hydra's Ax plugin does not currently have a config group for configuring this `max_parallelism` setting, so it is automatically set by ax.

Loading the data outside of main (as you suggested) may be a good workaround for this issue.

Comment: Hi @Jasha ! thanks for the answer, and sorry for the late reply. Thank you for the detailed answer, although I'm not that familiar with all the details around AX I'll accept this answer. Unfortunately the dataloading process also takes some config parameters from hydra, so moving it out is quite non-trivial. I've raised an issue in hydra github. Otherwise I guess I'll move out the data loading part, and do any modifications to it inside `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Hydra sweepers in general does not have a facility to control concurrency. This is the responsibility of the launcher you are using.
The built-in basic launcher runs the jobs serially so it should not trigger memory issues.
If you are using other launchers, you may need to control their parallelism via Launcher specific parameters.